# how to remove django evolution from admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-evolution

How to unregister django-evolution from admin?

```
admin.site.unregister( something )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `admin.site` has also an `unregister()` method, you need to pass it the model class of the admin you want to unregister!

```
from django_evolution.models import Version, Evolution
admin.site.unregister(Version)
admin.site.unregister(Evolution)
```

Put it in any module that is loaded on startup after the evolution app, for example in `admin.py` of an app that comes in `INSTALLED_APPS` AFTER evolution!